# React, Reactstrap - Input vs input, form-control class prevents values from submitting, returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, forms, bootstrap-4, reactstrap, form-control

I am working on an basic React CRUD App and I came across a strange issue.
Using **Reactstrap Input Component** or the bootstrap **class="form-control"** the input values are undefined onSubmit.
If I leave the elements as a standard html input the values submit just fine?
I cannot figure out why this is happening.
I put together this demo that illustrates the issue.

[**Code Sandbox Snippet** <- Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/403jy5ynp9)

On the **AddName.js** file I have one **Input** and one **input** on submit you can see that the first name submits but the description does not.

```js
<FormGroup>
  <input
    placeholder="First Name"
    ref={nameInput => (this.nameInput = nameInput)}
  />
</FormGroup>
<FormGroup>
  <Input
    placeholder="Description"
    ref={descriptionInput => (this.descriptionInput = descriptionInput)}
  />
</FormGroup>
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Is it possible how I have the refs on the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before utilizing 3rd party packages, you should read into using [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) strictly through React. Then, once you understand the flow, incorporate the packages.

I've rewritten your project to include all of the above, as well as written notes describing what I changed and why. There are also a few tricks and shortcuts I've used to simplify the code, such as: [setState callback](https://alligator.io/react/getting-atomic-updates-with-setstate/#functional-setstate), [ES6 Object Deconstruction](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#sec_overview-destructuring) and [Fat Arrow Functions](https://hackernoon.com/getting-to-grips-with-es6-arrow-functions-ebfa62c5c5d6).

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/l9m0vor4wq

You should only need to use `refs` for obtaining a DOM element or a class instance for UI manipulation, instead of obtaining a data value. For example, utilizing a `ref` to draw attention to a DOM element via using its `focus()` method or removing attention from it via its `blur()` method. In your case, we would only use the synthetic `event` instead of a ref.

On a side note, be careful about using the `name` as a key in `<PersonCard/>`, because multiple users can share the same `name` value. This will cause React to complain that two keys are the same, and cause issues if you ever try to remove, resort, or filter the names list. To keep it simple, I instead used the `key` provided by the map function. While this approach works, it's not the best solution. Ideally, each person should have an `id` property with a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). This ensures all of your keys will be unique.

Comment: Thanks @matt for the awesome explanation. I am new to React and there is so much to take in. I was suspicious of using refs seen in a youtube tutorial. event.target is much more familiar and now that I see it makes much more sense.

Comment: can you also explain how I would create the methods for Update and Delete assuming I am using an id for the key prop?

Comment: That should be a good challenge for you tackle on your own. That said, if you're using a unique id, it'll simply the challenge. Give it a shot. If you get stuck, show me via a codesandbox what you've tried and I can give some feedback.